# Can I ask for an explanation of an answer on somebody else's question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I was checking through the questions on DSP Stack Exchange and found a  question that I was also curious about. So i was following the question to see any solutions. An answer has been  given by a well known DSP Stack Exchange member which I am unable to clearly understand. The person who has asked the question hasn't commented or asked any further clarification. He hasn't even upvoted it or marked it as correct. so can I go forward and add a comment saying can you please elaborate the answer to person who has answered the question in the comments section of his answer. The hesitation I have is that it is not my question he has answered to. So can I do that or not?

Answer (score 4):

You can do a couple of things here...

1. Leave a comment asking for clarification. *Be specific* about what in the answer confuses you. The answerer might return to update it.
2. Post a new question, referencing the answer to the existing question and describing what you found confusing about it (again, *be specific!*)

Note that #2 has the advantage of allowing *anyone* to jump in and provide a clarifying answer - this is particularly useful when the answer may be perfectly understandable to someone knowledgeable in the field but somewhat opaque to those with less experience.

Note also that you can *combine* #1 and #2 by asking a new question and then offering a link to it in a comment on the original answer...

Comment: I'd go with #1 immediately and, after a suitable time, do #2.